# Opens App when another Closes

Tags: windows, automation

I found this solution on your site but my needs are slightly different and I could not find a solution in the archive.

Here is a script that starts Notepad and then MS Paint. If you terminate Paint, then the CMD proceeds to kill Notepad.

```
start notepad.exe
mspaint.exe
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
pause
```

I need for an app to start when another closes instead.
So maybe someone can edit the above to:
start mspaint when notepad closes.

Let me also explain my entire process because it might be possible to include all in one batch file??

1. If App#1 starts, then App#2 must also start
2. If App#1 closed then App#3 must start

Answer (score 1):

This example `.bat` file will demonstrate how this is done:

```
start "App1" Echo App1. Close me manually!
start "App2" Echo App2. Close me manually!
:waitapp1
timeout /T 2 /nobreak >nul
tasklist.exe /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq App1" | find ":" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto waitapp1
start "App3" Echo App3. Close me manually!
echo Finished!
```

You may use other filters of the
[tasklist command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist).
Perhaps you would prefer using IMAGENAME over WINDOWTITLE.

Answer (score 0):

```
notepad.exe
mspaint.exe
```

You can experiment with and without `start` before the app names to see the difference.